# IPython notebook: Browser crashed, is it possible to reconnect to running session/kernel

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook running for some hours, I came back in the morning and at some point the browser crashed. I can see that the kernel is still running and computing.

If I open the browser and open the notebook again, it seems as it opens the file, but does not really connect to the existing running kernel. I judge this by the fact that the notebook does not show the "kernel busy" badge on the top.

What I really would like to do is, is to connect to the running kernel with a qtconsole, interrupt the process, go into debug mode and save the important variables, shut down the kernel properly and continue the process with the data I saved.

Now is there a way of connecting to a running kernel with a qtconsole?

For future reference:

Alternatively one could also wait until the process finished the computation and then hook into the session and save the results (but this works only if the kernel is idle, hence the question is still open):

Just copy the hash from the terminal that started the ipyhton notebook and then link into the session with:

`ipython console --existing 08906ba1-7942-4309-9955-712efdeb09f9`

or

`ipython qtconsole --existing 08906ba1-7942-4309-9955-712efdeb09f9`

(`08906ba1-7942-4309-9955-712efdeb09f9` being the hash)

Comment: It should be perfectly possible to reconnect, but you might not be able to do much until it finishes the calculation. The lack of the 'kernel busy' notification probably isn't an issue - that is displayed in response to a message sent when it starts executing code, so it won't reappear if you reconnect.

Comment: Yes it seems to be possible to reconnect, but I would like to interrupt the running process as well.

Comment: What version of IPython do you have? I don't think we use UUIDs to identify kernels like that any more.

Comment: It'd be really nice if, like screen/tmux, re-attaching to a kernel could show you everything you'd seen before (and has happened since the disconnect)... including progressive output from a currently-running cell. But that doesn't seem to be yet supported.